# Condição IF entre tabelas MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

OPa,

Tenho duas tabelas: `forma_pagamento` e `forma_pagamento_selecionada`.

Tenho um while onde devem ser listadas todas formas de pagamento, logo, neste while deve se ter uma condição `IF`onde irá me retornar uma nova coluna, caso, sejam encontrados valores iguais entre as duas tabelas, exemplo, que não funcionou.

```
SELECT
  *,
  IF(forma_pagamento_selecionado_id = forma_pagamento_id, NULL, 'checked') AS isChecked
FROM 
  forma_pagamento_selecionado
INNER JOIN
  forma_pagamento ON forma_pagamento_id = forma_pagamento_selecionado_id
```

Ou seja, caso a `forma_pagamento_selecionado_id` seja igual a `forma_pagamento_id`, o `isCheckd` receberá o valor 'checked', caso não seja igual, não receberá valor.

Comment: Cara dá uma lida em COALESCE MySql, será que não atende suas necessidades? Pois tu testa as condições por parametro até achar uma que não seja null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da forma como tu estás relacionando com `INNER JOIN` sempre será retornado os valores onde  `forma_pagamento_id` é igual a `forma_pagamento_selecionado_id`, então o `if` ali será inútil além de estar declarado de forma incorreta.

Já que você quer listar todos os resultados, iguais ou não, use o `LEFT JOIN` e o `IF` da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT forma_pagamento_selecionado.*, 
IF(forma_pagamento.ID IS NULL, 'NULL', 'Checked') AS isChecked
FROM forma_pagamento_selecionado
LEFT JOIN forma_pagamento 
ON forma_pagamento.ID = forma_pagamento_selecionado.ID
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5a02/11)

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, graças a ideia do @Marcelo de Andrade

```
SELECT
      forma_pagamento_id,
      forma_pagamento_nome,
      forma_pagamento_selecionado_id,
      IF(forma_pagamento_selecionado_id IS NULL, 'NULL', '1') AS forma_pagamento_aceita
FROM
    forma_pagamento
LEFT JOIN
     forma_pagamento_selecionado ON forma_pagamento.forma_pagamento_id = forma_pagamento_selecionado.forma_pagamento_selecionado_id 
and
     forma_pagamento_selecionado_id = 1
```

Vlw